# xcode git pull/push crash

Tags: xcode, git, github

When using the xCode IDE when selecting file -> Source Control -> Pull or Push xCode crashes. The only workaround so far found for this is to load the organiser and select each repository and click pull then when then repository name displays cancel the dialog. After repeating this for each repository the normal push/pull options work fine until Xcode is restarted and then the process must be repeated.

This happens the same on all machines (4) at our office. The repositories are on github and there are multiple repositories being loaded in for each project.

We having been using the work around for some time but as we get more repositories this becomes more of an annoyance. Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: I'm on 4.3.2 and another machine with same problem is on 4.3.3

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem, but a workaround. I use [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) rather than relying on XCode for Git. XCode plays nicely with this, and doesn't freak out when Git changes open files.

Comment: Wow, @RobGill, thanks for the workaround with the organizer!  As much as this is a pain in the ass, at least I can actually pull now.  I find that pulling on the command line leads to me having to merge conflicts in the project files which are a maze of XML.  XCode, as much as it is about as stable as a meth addict, at least does a good job of merging those files.

Comment: Thats strange using xCode I find that when files are added and removed at the same time by different people we have to manually resolve the conflicts in the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issues with Xcode 4.3 so I have been using Xcode 4.4 and 4.5 for development (I'm not close the delivering yet, so it doesn't matter than I cannot submit my App using these versions yet).

An alternative would be to use an external source control tool; I would recommend [SourceTree](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/) as it's free and works well.  Other than that, there is always the command line.

Comment: Does SourceTree do a good job with the XCode-specific project files?  I find that XCode merges those files well, but dealing with conflicts in the project files by hand, after merging on the command line, is a nightmare.

Comment: @adriandz It doesn't have specific support for Xcode project files AFAIK.

Comment: I really tested Xcode and git and other tools to have the best possible workflow. I like SourceTree a lot, but more effective than that is the really good [Gitbox](http://www.gitboxapp.com/). I use it SOO MUCH! For really special things in git I recommend the terminal. @adriandz For merging complex things use command line command `git mergetool` as you get a merge error in Gitbox. It brings you to FileMerge (shipped with Xcode) and there you have a very neat merge resolution!!! Save - quit File Merge - automatically come back to the terminal. Do it again, if you have additional conflicts

Comment: one thing I forgot: To use FileMerge add diff or mergetool just type the following in the terminal:  `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` - a relict of times before Xcode.app and the Mac App Store Version